# Custom geometry and singlespacing don't work together

Tags: geometry

In my twosided-document I have activated \onehalfspacing and different pagemargins for even/odd pages. But in my titlepage, I want to use singlespacing and equal pagemargins.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
twoside
openright
12pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[
inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm,                                        
top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,
includeheadfoot
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{singlespacing}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm} 

\begin{center}
            \framebox[10cm]{Logo here\vspace*{3cm}}
        \par
        \vspace*{10ex}
\Huge
\vfill
            \textsc{\textbf{How to use LaTeX}}\\
            \normalsize The same title in another languafe
\vfill
\noindent Berlin, November 2017
    \end{center}
%\vfill
\end{singlespacing}

\restoregeometry
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

The problem is, that the newgeometry-command has no effect as long I use singlespacing. When I delete the singlespacing-command, the pagemargins are equal. But I want to make both work. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. After posting and taking a last look on the code I discovered my mistake:

The newgeometry-command (and the pagestyle-, too) has to be placed **before** the singlespacing-environment. Then everything works.